# Insert custom fields to a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, child-theme

I am creating a small blog about my trekking and camping experience. Since different experiences - like campsites, treks and tour operators - have different metadata, [I have created a custom post types (e.g. `campsite`), associated with custom field types (e.g. `price`, `water_supply`)](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/adding-custom-fields-to-a-custom-post-type-the-right-way).

Now I'm trying to use these fields in my child theme. I've copied twenty-twelve - the parent - `single.php` to `single-campsite.php`, and started digging in.

The problem is that the entire post content - title, content, and date - is created from this single line:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

**How do I edit the post internals, e.g. insert custom fields between the title and the contents, or remove the date below?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement grabs a file called content-post-format.php in the theme directory, depending on the post format. Posts will grab content.php since there is no post format.

Copy the information out of content.php into single-campsite.php and go from there. Alternatively, you can create a copy of content.php called content-campsite.php and call:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'campsite' ); ?>
```

Comment: +1 Great. The concept of `get_template_part` is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little at first but it's nice to keep your theme organized by section. I use this for comments, post data, all kinds of things.

Comment: What's the general idea behind this function?

Comment: A simple API to include theme files correctly. It basically concatenates the first string and the last string with a dash in the middle and looks for that file name with a PHP extension. If it doesn't find that, it falls back on just the first string for a file name. Basically, it tries for a specific file but has a fall back if not.